# In what scenario could an AJAX request not have the cookies set by the page which fired the AJAX?

Tags: http, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

Some small percentage of the time, we see a flow like this, deducing from looking at server logs (I have not been able to reproduce this case with any browser):

1. At time A, client hits our page:

   - with no cookies
   - gets back a response with a `Set-Cookie` HTTP response header that gives them a session id of B
   - body has JS to fire an AJAX request `/ajax/foo`.
2. At time A + 1 second, client hits us with the AJAX request to `/ajax/foo`

   - the referrer is set to the page in step 1 that fired the AJAX, as expected
   - with no cookies - why?
   - gets back a response with a `Set-Cookie` header that gives them a session id of C (expected, since they didn't send us a cookie)
3. At some time slightly later, all of the client requests are sending either session id B or C - so the problem is *not* that the browser has cookies turned off.

This seems to be essentially a race condition -- the main page request and the AJAX request come in together very close in time, both with no cookies, and there is a race to set the cookie. One wins and one loses.

What is puzzling to me is how could this happen? My assumption is that by time the browser has read enough of the response to know that it needs to fire an AJAX request, it has already received the HTTP response headers and thus the `Set-Cookie` response header. So it seems to me that the client would always send back the cookie that we set in the page that fired the AJAX request. I just don't see how this could happen unless the browser is not promptly processing the `Set-Cookie` response.

Like I said, I can't reproduce this in Firefox, Safari, or Chrome, but we do see it several times a day.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new feature in google chrome that could cause this misbehavior. It is called prerender.

> Prerendering is an experimental feature in Chrome (versions 13 and up)
> that can take hints from a site’s author to speed up the browsing
> experience of users. A site author includes an element in HTML that
> instructs Chrome to fetch and render an additional page in advance of
> the user actually clicking on it.
>
> Even if you do not proactively trigger prerendering yourself, it is
> still possible that another site will instruct Chrome to prerender
> your site. If your page is being prerendered, it may or may not ever
> be shown to the user (depending on if the user clicks the link). In
> the vast majority of cases, you shouldn’t have to do anything special
> to handle your page being prerendered—it should just work.

For more information read: http://code.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender.html

**Edit:**
You could trigger prerender on your page with: http://prerender-test.appspot.com/

Comment: That's a pretty good idea, thanks, but I don't think that's it as I've seen it with a bunch of different user agents, which are not Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

a) Does the cookie have an expiration time?

b) If so, have you tried to reproduce it by setting the computer's clock back or forward by more than the TTL of the cookie? (I mean the clock of the computer running the browser, obviously; not the server running the app ... which should be a separate computer whose clock is set accurately.)

I've seen this as well; it seems to be triggered by users with screwed up system clocks. The cookie was sent with an expiration date that, from the browser's perspective, was already past.

Comment: That is an interesting idea. Thanks! I have since switched companies so this issue is no longer on my radar, but I may refer back to this sometime later if I see a similar issue. Thanks again!